# Swift & Firebase - Split data for user info?

Tags: swift, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I currently coding a fitness app that permits to record all the personal records for a user.

I'm really new with Cloud Firestore from Firebase, so I really don't know how I could structure the database.

In my mind, I have two options:

OPTION 1

> ```
> Users
>  |
>  +--UserID
>  |   |
>  |   +--Name
>  |   +--Phone
>  |   +--etc..
>  |
>  |
> Users-records
>  |
>  +--UserID
>  |   |
>  |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   |
>  |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   +--recordType
>  |   | 
>  |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   +--recordType
> ```

OPTION 2

> ```
> Users
>  |
>  +--UserID
>  |   |
>  |   +--Name
>  |   +--Phone
>  |   +--etc..
>  |   +--Records
>  |   |   |
>  |   |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   |   |
>  |   |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   |   +--recordType
>  |   |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   |   |
>  |   |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   |   +--recordType
> ```

The questions are: Do I have to split the collection for the user? 
Do you think this architecture is well designed for the purpose (ie record personal records from users)?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you have to go with second options because when you need the inner structure data then you don't need to call multiple api's and you can access the data in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure really depends on how you are going to use it. Keep in mind that whenever you observe a node, you are also observing all of the children nodes.

So I'd probably go with something closer to Option two, maybe like this:

> ```
> Users
>  |
>  +--UserID
>  |   |
>  |   +--UserInfo
>  |   |   |
>  |   |   +--Name
>  |   |   +--Phone
>  |   |   +--etc..
>  |   |
>  |   +--Records
>  |   |   |
>  |   |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   |   |
>  |   |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   |   +--recordType
>  |   |   +--RecordName
>  |   |   |   |
>  |   |   |   +--recordValue
>  |   |   |   +--recordType
> ```

I'd choose this, because I'd image you'd want to get all of the UserInfo at once, So we can observe that "UserInfo" node and get all of the children: name, phone, etc....

Then I'd think you'd also want to get all of the records at once, so we can observe that "Records" node and get all of that data.

Additionally, if you wanted, you could get everything at once by observing the UserID!

However, if you were maybe going to be getting a list of all the users, then you definitely don't want all this data in one spot and this design wouldn't work, because that is a lot of data to observe just to get all the users.

**In summary:** Choose an option which makes it easiest for you to get what you need, without getting extra data you don't want!